# printer isn't working

Tags: printing

I have Ubuntu 19, and a samsung m2020 printer it is hooked up by usb,in printer settings it says it is ready. Nothing prints when I try to print something, accidentally deleted my windows partition so I am trying to make do with Ubuntu and this is my major pet peeve I can never get the printer to work

Comment: have you downloaded and installed the linux driver for the printer from here https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/samsung-xpress-sl-m2020-laser-printer-series/16462592

Comment: how do you install the tar.gz file? I extract hoping for an .sh file and it turned into a folder

Comment: there should be an install.sh in the folder

Comment: I found the install printer driver.sh file, installed it  in terminal but not sure how this set up anything? because it didn't open the printer set up or anything. and it definitely is not working.